# Can you chose fewer targets than a spell permits?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a spell like [Victimize](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Victimize) that says, among other things "choose two target creature cards in your graveyard"...  what if I only have one creature card in my graveyard? Can I still cast the spell? Do I need to have two valid legal targets to actually cast the spell?

Comment: Additional note: You can't target the same object twice by a single instance of the word "target".

Comment: If you could choose to not target anything, then you could play something like Aether Tradewinds and choose no target you control.

Comment: For more precise wording you can choose fewer target than a spell 'permits' (e.g. up to two targets can be 0, 1 or 2) but not fewer than it 'requires' (e.g. two targets can only be 2). There's also the distinction between separate instances of the word target (Decimate can target a single Artifact Enchantment Land Creature four times, but each instance of the word target needs to be valid, while Victimize needs two distinct targets).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't. You need to specify all targets. It would say "up to two targets" if you could target less. That is also for example the downside of the card [Hex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247382).

Comment: And to see "up to" in action, see Cruel Revival, which is deliberately worded so that you can kill something without needing a zombie to get back.